# How do I get rid of this warning in iOS 7 Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have the following code for NSURLSession

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
HomeViewController* hvc= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:hvc delegateQueue:    [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url ];
[dataTask setAccessibilityLabel:@"UserProfiling"];
[dataTask resume];
```

The compiler shows a warning at this statement:

```
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:hvc delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

and the warning is :

```
Sending 'HomeViewController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSURLSessionDelegate>'
```

How do I remove this warning?

I have confirmed to the delegates by writing:

```
@interface ProfileTabView : UIViewController <NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
{

}
```

Basically, I am calling a NSURLSessionDataTask and the delegates are in another ViewController as you see above.

Comment: HomeViewController is not the class you've added the protocol conformance to (ProfileTabView).

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. I was confused because the delegates were present in a different ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From a comment, making answer for posterity.)

HomeViewController is not the class you've added the protocol conformance to (ProfileTabView).